# How to organize data environment for JUnit tests?

Tags: java, junit, dbunit

I'm creating a data-intensive Java EE web application, which keeps its persistent data in a relational database. Now I want some JUnit tests to validate the application behavior in certain "data environments". Some objects should be created before tests and destroyed when tests are finished. Tests should be able to control their data setup configuration. Typical situation, huh? Now my questions are:

- What tools to use for it? [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) looks rather old and is not JUnit-4 oriented.
- Where to place and how to name object creators?
- How to pass configuration details to them? Java call params? XML configs?
- Shouldn't I use [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html) JUnit rule for convenience?

I'm interested to know what are the best practices. How do you solve this problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this. "Best practices" questions aren't always bad, but this is very broad, and you're asking multiple questions in one post.

Comment: "DBUnit looks rather old and is not JUnit-4 oriented" I use DBUnit with JUnit 4 and have zero problems - what are you referring to?

Comment: @Lord exactly, there are many broad questions in my post, but I'm expecting one single short answer, which will point me to the right direction

Comment: @matt to this in particular: [`...extends DBTestCase`](http://www.dbunit.org/howto.html). Extending test case classes is a technology from junit-3.

Comment: You don't need to extend DBTestCase to use DBUnit; looks like that is purely for convenience. You can configure the dataSet on your own in a @Before method.

Comment: A slightly different way would be not using DB or any persistence at all in tests -- use some Mock framework instead, if you can.

Answer (score 3):

DBUnit is rather old and there is no more innovation in this project since 2009. The main problem is the heavy usage of XML for dataSet. Creation of dataset is hard but feasible. Maintenance is a nightmare and sometime too expensive...

If you use entities with an ORM framework you should try to use them directly for instantiating your database. I recommend Unitils for this, which help the configuration of the test database and provide the injection of JPA or Hibernate Session. You can combine this approach with the Builder Pattern to express the meaning of the datas and centralise the configuration.

Comment: additionally Unitils has a dbunit subproject that is maintained.